# The input data is not a complete block crytographic exception c#

Tags: c#

Feels like the error message is not clear so i had to paste all of my work . Thank you for having a look. I have pasted all my screenshots.

```
        using System;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Security.Cryptography;            
        namespace ConsoleApp5    
{
        class Program
        {    
        //SALT is a random data that is used as addition to a password to encrypt data
        // The primary function is to protect against lists of often used password
        private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[] {0x26,0xdc,0xff,0x76,0x76,                                                                        0xad,0xed,0x7a,0x64,0xc5,0xfe                                                                        ,0x20,0xaf,0x4d,0x08,0x3c};
        public static void Encrypt()
        {
            string Password = "password";  //as i want 
            string fileIn = @"C:\SourceFolder\Source.txt";
            string fileOut = @"C:\DestinationFolder\Destination.txt";

            //open filestreat for encrypted source file
            using (System.IO.FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                using (System.IO.FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Create Key and IV from the password with the SALT 
                        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, SALT);

                        //Create a symmetric algorithm with Rijndael
                        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

                        //alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                        //alg.BlockSize = 128;          
                        alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

                        alg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                        //SET key and IV 
                        alg.Key = pdf.GetBytes(32);
                        alg.IV = pdf.GetBytes(16);
                        //Create a cryptoStream 


                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            //Intialize the buffer and process the input in chunks 
                            // this is done to avoid reading the whole file which is huge and memory consumption. 
                            int bufferLen = 4096;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                            int bytesRead;
                            do
                            { //read a chunck of data from the input file 
                                bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

                                //Encrypt it 
                                cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            while (bytesRead != 0);

                            //close everything 
                            cs.Close();              // Fails here 
                            fsOut.Close();
                            fsIn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var error = ex.Message;
                        var stackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Encrypt();
        }
    }
}
```

**ErrorMessage:** [image]

My Destination File has the encrypted data. I dont know why the error shows up.
**Myfiles:** 
[image]

As you can see the destination.txt file has the encrypted data.

**Now when i decrypt it. 
using following code**

```
 public static void Decrypt()
       {
           string Password = "password";  //as i want 
            string fileIn = @"C:\DestinationFolder\Destination.txt";// @"C:\SourceFolder\Source.txt";
            string fileOut = @"C:\SourceFolder\x.txt";// @"C:\DestinationFolder\Destination.txt";
            //open filestreat for encrypted source file
            using (System.IO.FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(fileIn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                using (System.IO.FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(fileOut, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Create Key and IV from the password with the SALT 
                        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, SALT);

                        //Create a symmetric algorithm with Rijndael
                        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

                        alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                        //alg.BlockSize = 128;
                        //SET key and IV 

                        alg.Key = pdf.GetBytes(32);
                        alg.IV = pdf.GetBytes(16);
                        //Create a cryptoStream 
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOut, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            //Intialize the buffer and process the input in chunks 
                            // this is done to avoid reading the whole file which is huge and memory consumption. 

                            int bufferLen = 4096;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                            int bytesRead;
                            do
                            { //read a chunck of data from the input file 
                                bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

                                //Decrypt it 
                                cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            while (bytesRead != 0);

                            //close everything 
                            cs.Close();   //this is where it throws exception
                            fsOut.Close();
                            fsIn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var error = ex.Message;

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It does not throw an error but my decrypt file looks like this which feels like it is encrypting again rather than decryting. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you've got several different problems going on.

First up: Padding.  The error you're getting about invalid size is because you've set the padding to none.  Look at the comments in your code above, where it sets how to handle byte chunks that aren't divisible by what the encryption algorithm sets.  If you don't have padding set to something, it won't let you encrypt files that aren't cleanly divisible.

Next, take a look at how you're setting up the encryption.  Where you're setting up your CryptoStream, you're asking it to create a new *decryptor*, not an encryptor.  Also, at that point, you do *not* want to write to the CryptoStream - you want to *read* from it, since you're *not* providing the input data to it (the file is.)

Also, you shouldn't need to manually manage the byte chunks like this.  The Stream readers/writers should be able to take care of it for you.

Finally, you should really try to refactor your code before posting it here - it'll make troubleshooting a lot easier.

Anyways, here's what I've got:

```
    private static readonly byte[] SALT = new byte[] { 0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x76, 0x76, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0x64, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x20, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x3c };
    public static void Encrypt()
    {
        string fileIn = @"C:\tmp.txt";
        string fileOut = @"C:\tmpEnc.txt";
        try
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm alg = GetAlgorithm();
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(fileIn))
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(streamIn.BaseStream, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(fileOut))
                cs.CopyTo(streamOut.BaseStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
            var stackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

            throw;
        }
    }
    public static void Decrypt()
    {
        string fileIn = @"C:\tmpEnc.txt";
        string fileOut = @"C:\tmpDec.txt";
        try
        {
            SymmetricAlgorithm alg = GetAlgorithm();
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(fileIn))
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(streamIn.BaseStream, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(fileOut))
                cs.CopyTo(streamOut.BaseStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
            var stackTrace = ex.StackTrace;

            throw;
        }
    }

    private static SymmetricAlgorithm GetAlgorithm()
    {
        string Password = "password";  //as i want 

        //Create Key and IV from the password with the SALT 
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Password, SALT);

        //Create a symmetric algorithm with Rijndael
        Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

        //alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        //alg.BlockSize = 128;          
        alg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        //SET key and IV 
        alg.Key = pdf.GetBytes(32);
        alg.IV = pdf.GetBytes(16);
        //Create a cryptoStream 

        return alg;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this for spending time and analyzing code. I did put paddingmode to PKCS7 but dont know why i put it back to None.